# Assign variable a value from a key value pair in shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file:

```
key1=b
key2=d
```

I want to find and assign a variable in the shell script with b(value from the key).

I am using:

```
var=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/^key1=//p')
```

but `var=$file`

I cannot get the sed to work properly to get var=b.

Comment: How about `source $file; var=$key1`?

Comment: Don't want to use source statement @Beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the solution. Hope it helps others

```
var=$(sed -n 's/^key1=//p' "$file")
```